# actionScript3 ENTER_FRAME Event is not working

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to to use the ENTER_FRAME Event on playing audio ,but the code is not executing the handler function.

```
public function play_mp3(path:String,path1:String):void {
    var snd:Sound = new Sound();
    snd.load(new URLRequest(path), new SoundLoaderContext());
    channel = snd.play();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);} 
 public function myFunction(e:Event){
  LogFB.info('test1234'); }
```

Comment: Where is this code located? `ENTER_FRAME` only works on display objects that are currently drawn in the frame, meaning that they have to be on the display list. In essence this means that only DisplayObjects are capable of using `ENTER_FRAME` events. To get around this in non-DisplayObject Classes, you could make a simple variable (like a Sprite, MovieClip, Shape), add it to your displaylist outside of the class, and add the eventlistener to the variable.

Comment: Hello DodgerThud,
I believe it's a non-display object, and i have already created the above varables(like a Sprite, MovieClip, Shape) .
My Main Issue is to calculate percentage of played part of playing mp3 and Add and event on that.
I hope you can help me on this .

Comment: Where is this code located?  If you try putting this in your `play_mp3` method:   `LogFB.info('stage: ' + stage);` do you get a stage object or null?    If the latter, then the problem is as DodgerThud suggests, the context of that class is not on the display tree so ENTER_FRAME will never be dispatched.

Comment: Hello LDMS,
Thank you for replying.
I went throgh as you suggested and it says 
[class Stage]

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're issue is likely that the class whose code you've posted, is not on the display tree. (it's not a display object or hasn't been added to the stage).

If it's not on the display tree, then `ENTER_FRAME` will not dispatch on it.

You can get around this a few ways.

1. Pass into the class a reference to something that is on the stage (or the stage itself). Then add the ENTER_FRAME listener on that object.

   ```
   var stage:Stage;
   public function MyClass(stage_:Stage){
       stage = stage_;
   }

   ....
   stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, myFunction);
   ```
2. Forgo ENTER_FRAME, and just use a `Timer`

   ```
   var timer:Timer
   public function play_mp3(path:String,path1:String):void {
       var snd:Sound = new Sound();
       snd.load(new URLRequest(path), new SoundLoaderContext());
       channel = snd.play();
       timer = new Timer(250); //tick every quarter second
       timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, myFunction);
       timer.start();
   } 

   public function myFunction(e:Event){
     LogFB.info('test1234');
   }
   ```

Comment: Hey,
It's(Forgo ENTER_FRAME, and just use a Timer) worked for me,
Thank you so much.
one small issue i have here,i want to call the myfunction after playing audio completes 50%.
I have total length of audio but time =new timer(totallength/2) doesn't work exactly i want.i believe this is because audio is still loading

Comment: Check for `snd.bytesLoaded < snd.bytesTotal` to see if the sound is fully loaded, if not, the listen for the `Event.COMPLETE` event:    `snd.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, soundReady);`  then start the timer

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is in LogFB. 
Try this and you will see the trace from inside the function...

```
   var channel : SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();

function play_mp3(path:String,path1:String):void {
    var snd:Sound = new Sound();
    snd.load(new URLRequest(path), new SoundLoaderContext());
    channel = snd.play();
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
} 

function myFunction(e:Event){
    //LogFB.info('test1234'); here is the problem
   // trace("is working!");
    hi();
}

play_mp3('aasa','aaa');

function hi() {
    trace("goooooddddd!"); //is working, I am using Flash CC
}
```

**All the best!**

Comment: I don't think so,
What if i leave the trace and call another function test() from myFunction(),this also not working.
And I am using Intellij Idea IDE ,trace doesn't work in browser.
Also LogFb.info is working everywhere in the program

Answer (score -1):

there doesnt seem any error try this one

```
public function play_mp3(path:String,path1:String):void {
 addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,myFunction);
    var snd:Sound = new Sound();
    snd.load(new URLRequest(path), new SoundLoaderContext());
    channel = snd.play();
   } 
 public function myFunction(e:Event){
  LogFB.info('test1234'); }
```

ie put the enterframe event the first thing that hapen in your code to check if at least it initialise it?

Comment: No it didn't work.
Actually the issue is this event(Event.ENTER_FRAME) is not working anywhere in class.

Comment: have you imported the Event enter frame event?

Comment: Are you talking about flash.event.Event,yes